# Pr2 whirling like a dervish

Tags: ros, pr2, dwa-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When using the [pr2_2dnav_local](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_2dnav_local) and setting a goal very close to an obstacle, the robot starts rotating in place. My guess is that this is related to the dynamic window controller, which can't find a suitable set of commands, even if the planner says the goal target is in a free cell. I've read the guide [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide), but I didn't find anything to solve this problem.

What parameters of the dwc should I change to avoid this effect?

A broader question is, would you use the default navigation stack to get close to an object (say a table) or do I need a custom package for that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11500/pr2-whirling-like-a-dervish/) by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1342 on 2011-10-11

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on 2011-10-12**:
thanks :-D

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-10-11**:
Thumbs up for the question title! :-)

**Comment by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on 2011-10-11**:
Several whirling robotic dervishes then!

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-10-11**:
I don't have a solution, but this is a failure mode I've experienced myself, as have several others. At least you aren't alone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Lorenzo, you should try the "base_local_planner", which was default until cturtle. It does not have this spinning problem at all. The DWA local planner can be fun to watch, but you might be bored of this spinning behavior.

The default configuration file in pr2_navigation_config/move_base/base_local_planner_params.yaml will work well, but if you add the parameter "min_vel_x" to "0.10", the planner will be slightly more robust.

---

Originally posted by [watts](https://answers.ros.org/users/99/watts/) with karma: 584 on 2011-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JuergenHess](https://answers.ros.org/users/370/juergenhess/) on 2012-01-22**:
Hi Lorenzo, did you solve the problem? We got the same here in Freiburg. If the robot gets too close to obstacles on the way or at the goal it does not finish rotating and does not continue the path. I have played around with the move_base parameters but was not able to fix it.

**Comment by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on 2011-10-12**:
base_local_planner  solves the problem. in that the robot reaches the point. but then it get's stuck and it doesn't move anymore, even if it has reached a goal position. I guess there is still some fine tuning to do, but things are getting better.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have uploaded a set of parameters that "work" in the University of Ulster repository. The package is [here](http://github.com/uu-isrc-robotics/uu-isrc-robotics-pr2-pkgs/tree/master/good_pr2_local_nav).

The launch folder has a pr2_2dnav.launch that uses the correct parameters, listed in the params folder.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) with karma: 1342 on 2012-01-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JuergenHess](https://answers.ros.org/users/370/juergenhess/) on 2012-01-23**:
Thanks. I will try that.